# Showing a dialogue after file has been uploaded (Ajax/PHP/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I am using Javascript with AJAX to send form data to a PHP file. Once it's done uploading the file to the server, I want a dialogue box to appear to say it's successful, then it reloads. I have that dialogue box done, but it will appear even if there's an error. I though creating a flag would solve this, but it doesn't. I need to wait for the progress to be 100% complete, so I put the code in the progress function. Here's my code:

```
function uploadImage(){  
var done = false;
     var xr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        xr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
        xr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        xr.open("POST", "php/uploadImage.php", true);

        xr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xr.readyState == 4 && xr.status == 200){
                var response = xr.responseText;
                if(response=="success"){
                    done=true;
                }else{
                    _("errorMessage").innerHTML = response;
                }
            }
        }

        xr.send(formdata);

        function progressHandler(event){
            var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
            _("imageUploadBar").style.width = Math.round(percent) + "%";

            if((percent == 100) && (done)){
                completeHandler();
            }
        }

        function completeHandler(){
            bootbox.dialog({
                message: "Image upload is completed.",
                title: "Upload Success",
                buttons: {            
                    success: {
                        label: "Continue",
                        className: "btn btn-success",
                        callback: function() {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
}
```

So you can see that if the upload file return success, set done to be true, and if percent is 100, then fire, but this will not fire the `completeHandler()` function. Any ideas why or how to get around this?

Comment: Why don't you call `completeHandler` from the `onreadystatechange` function after checking the response?

Comment: I don't do this because it seems that when I try to upload larger files, the success dialogue pops up before the progress bar is done. So, to make it more appealing to users, I want it to wait till the progress bar is completed.

Comment: I don't see how that can be. You can't get status 200 until the server sends its response, and it won't do that until it has received the whole upload and processed it.

Comment: The only place you set `done` to `true` is in your ajax success, so I don't see how your `completeHandler` function could possibly trigger unless that code was hit. Have you tried adding `done = false` to the else block? Maybe it's set to true from a previous success.

Comment: @Barmer I'm not sure, but it seems to do that, or maybe it was just how I had some of my previous code setup.

JoshBjelovuk It gets set to false in this function, I should have showed that it was all wrapped in a function. I'll edit my code to show that. The first line is where done gets set to false.

Comment: But my point is the only place it ever gets set to true is in the success block, so there's no way it could trigger after an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will generally fire from onreadystatechange, but adding a 2nd variable should take care of your issue.

```
var done = false;
var uploaded = false;
var xr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
xr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
xr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
xr.open("POST", "php/uploadImage.php", true);

xr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xr.readyState == 4 && xr.status == 200){
        var response = xr.responseText;
        if(response=="success"){
            done=true;
            if(uploaded && done){
                completeHandler();
            }
        }else{
            _("errorMessage").innerHTML = response;
        }
    }
}

xr.send(formdata);

function progressHandler(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("imageUploadBar").style.width = Math.round(percent) + "%";

    if(percent == 100) uploaded = true;

    if(uploaded && done){
        completeHandler();
    }
}

function completeHandler(){
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: "Image upload is completed.",
        title: "Upload Success",
        buttons: {            
            success: {
                label: "Continue",
                className: "btn btn-success",
                callback: function() {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```